# How to test a php login connected to a mysql db through xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, directory, xampp

hello this is my first post on stackoverflow i am at beginner level at php, mysql and work on a php log in page connected to a mysql database which i did try to test through xampp and getting the following error message

```
Warning: include(../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php): failed to open stream: No such
file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storeadmin\admin_login.php 
on line 15

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php' for
inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore
\storeadmin\admin_login.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storeadmin\admin_login.php on line 18
That information is incorrect, try again Click Here
```

I was able to successfully connect to the mysql database through dreamwavercs6 on win7 64bit and created a user for the db as also i created a administrator with full privileges in the created admin table. With a successful log in it should direct you to a follow up page called `index.php` which is a second index page only for admins to choose tasks, located in a subfolder in the same directory. The home page `index.php` is located here `C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\index.php\`

the file with the script called `admin_login.php` is shown under here

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
header("location: index.php");
exit();
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["password"]);

include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND
password='$password' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount == 1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row["id"];
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
$_SESSION["password"] = $password;
header("location: index.php");
exit();
} else {
echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <ahref="index.php">Click Here</a>';
exit();
}
}
?>
```

the script `connect_to_mysql.php` under here

```
 <?php 
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "user"; 
$db_pass = "user"; 
$db_name = "myonlinestore_db";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to
mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");             
?>
```

the script `index.php` which is the landing page where on successful login from `admin_login` should redirect you to, under here

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
header("location: admin_login.php");
exit();
}
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '',$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]);

include"../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND
password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person

$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the nums
if ($existCount==0){//evaluate the count
echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database";
exit();
}
?>
```

the problem is that i can not log in through my firefox browser and getting the error as mentioned at the top. All addons,extensions in my firefox browser are on disable and accepting cookies is selected, can anyone help to fix this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Given you say you're working on an online store, you'd better learn about that and how to avoid it BEFORE your store gets hacked. While your preg_replace is making this particular query somewhat safe, you probably do have problems elsewhere.

Comment: It depends on your file structure. Is `index.php` located in the same directory as the script this excerpt is taken from?

Comment: index.php is the file where you should be directed to from the log in page, both are located in a sub folder in the same directory

Comment: Marc B thank you for the advice on vulnerability according to attacks and hacks, i will look into this later, first i am trying to learn how to test and build things in general, taking it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your script you are not being able to include your connect_to_mysql.php file.

```
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
```

You are trying to provide relative path. Make sure you are properly able to access that file from relative path you are including. i.e. your admin_login.php file.

You can try passing absolute path in your include:

```
include "C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storescripts\connect_to_mysql.php";
```

please check path in your file manager if it is correct absolute path.

Comment: can you look in to your file browser and get location for your connect_to_mysql.php location.

Comment: Hello askkirati thanks for trying to help, i did try and changed the path into absolute path but unfortunately this does not solve it and getting the same error message only with the relative path. the path in my file manager assuming you mean the landing page where the login page has to redirect you to, does not have a any path. The login script should redirect you to this page after it did check if the login name and password are correct according to the information in the mysql database.

Comment: location for the file connect_to_mysql.php in the browser is C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storescripts\connect_to_mysql.php

Comment: hello, I mean the absolute path to your connect_to_mysql.php in your computer. Where is it in your C drive. Full path to that file.

Comment: Are you sure you can access this file C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storescripts\connect_to_mysql.php

Comment: DIR should be \_\_DIR\_\_

Comment: Hello askkirati thanks again for trying to help i really appreciate it! please refresh your page i just did put both scripts connection_to_mysql and index.php on top of this page, thanks again!

Comment: did not work according to __DIR__ with underscores on both sides Failed opening '__DIR__../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php' for inclusion

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the dots from the `include("../`if the scripts are in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storescript.

From

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myonlinestore\storeadmin\admin_login.php

"../" will take you to htdocs, so you need "./" to get to `htdocs\myonlinestore`

Answer (score 0):

may be it will help you.

```
<?php
   $server = "localhost";
   $connection = mysqli_connect ($server,"root","","your_database_name");
   if(!$connection){
    // if not connected it will gives the error here
    echo "server not found".mysql_error();
}   
else{
    echo "Connected";
}
?>
```